# Executing an Alter Table statement generated by dynamic sql to a Linked Server

Tags: sql, dynamic, dynamic-sql, linked-server, alter-table

I have a situation that I need to add a field to a table over linked server. The specifications of this is dynamic and it is being done in TQL / Stored procedures and this can not change. My code is generating the statement just fine and if I copy paste it to a new SSMS window and execute it WORKS.. The problem is I need to dynamically generate the statement (I am doing that just fine, I THINK). THEN I need to execute the statement IN THE SPROC, this part is not working.

Here is the code:

```
SET @AlterSQL = @DestinationServerName + '.[' + @DestinationDBName +'].' + @DestinationSchemaName + '.sp_executesql N'' ALTER TABLE ' 
+ @DestinationTableName + ' ADD ' + @TempColumn + ' int' + CHAR(39)
```

The above Creates this when I expose it via a PRINT statement:

```
addb15.[FSParallel].dbo.sp_executesql N' ALTER TABLE Node ADD ImportIdentity int'
```

After I create the statement I use:

```
EXEC @AlterSQL
```

And this returns the following error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure ETLDynamicImport, Line 244
>   Could not find stored procedure 'FSParallel.dbo.sp_executesql N' ALTER
>   TABLE Node ADD ImportIdentity int''.

Can someone PLEASE advise on this? I am on a project Deadline and have googled this to no end and just can not get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing an `exec`.  Try:

```
exec sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE FSParallel.dbo.Node ADD ImportIdentity int';
```